# Shorthand operator for "OR"

Tags: javascript, php, operators, conditional-operator, shorthand

I am just wondering if there is any way to do something like:

```
if(myVar === 1|2|5) {do something}
```

or

```
if(myVar === (1 || 2 || 5)) { do something }
```

which will work as

```
if(myVar === 1 || myVar === 2 || myVar === 5) {do something}
```

Using switch case is not optional solution too. Also It should work with any data type not just numbers, but strings, arrays. basically a comparison. I have already tried the first two examples and it did not work, probably it's not meant to work like that.

I am specially interested in JS and PHP, other languages are welcome for other readers.

**UPDATE**

"in_array" or "indexOf" or writing an inline statement is not what kind of answer i am looking for. since i know about these functions I develop for 8+ years.

Let me explain:
Since I work with react I am learning JS and I have found lot of new tricks in javascript syntax like:

```
myArray.find(item => (item.id===something))  vs .find(function(item) {....})
const printHello = () => { return "hello" }  vs const printHello = function() { .... }
[1,2,3,4,...varWithOtherNumbers] vs concat
```

And lot of other tricks.

So I am just wondering if there is maybe a not well known javascript syntax trick.

Comment: your *and* is an *or*.

Comment: Oh thanks :D i will edit the question

Comment: PHP provides the [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking for more native way.

Comment: @ErikKubica then no, there's no shorter way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this?

```js
var a = 4;
if([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "something else"].indexOf(a) !== -1){
   console.log("It is a match!");
}
```

And in PHP you can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

I understand it is not a shorthand and a different approach altogether but yea this do the trick!

Comment: This is not a shorthand.. its a completely different implementation.

Comment: @CristianS. yea I understand that. But this approach comes in very handy when you have to compare with multiple values..

Comment: @CristianS. because such shorthand doesn't exist.

Comment: @axiax well then the answer is "such a shorthand doesnt exist"

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question to clarify what I am looking for. As i read the comments, there is no other answer for me then that syntax like this does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

**PHP**

```
$a = 5;

if(in_array($a, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
{
   echo "Gotcha!";
}
```

Even Shorter

```
echo in_array($a, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) ? "Found you" : "Not found";
```

**Python**

this guy has something even shorter version

```
>>> 4 in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // Outputs True
```

**Ruby**

```
[1, 2, 3].include ? 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question to clarify what I am looking for. As i read the comments, there is no other answer for me then, that syntax like this does not exists.